# Doctrine persistent collection convert to string for twig

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine, twig

How to convert an Objects of doctrine persistent collection to string?
What are the best practices?

```
public function usersOffers()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine();
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $influencer = $em->getRepository(Influencer::class)->find($user);
    $allApplications = $em->getRepository(Influencer::class)->find($influencer)->getApplications();

    return $this->render('users/offers.html.twig', [
           "applications" => $allApplications

    ]);
}
```

The line `"applications" => $allApplications` sends an Object to twig and can't convert it. On both of my entities I have a `__toString()`function.
I know before sending my value I have to convert it, but `json_encode()` sends an empty object.
I don't know how to properly resolve this issue.

Comment: You should provide a minimal reproducible example. You mention `json_encode()` but it is not in your code. The entire Twig is missing. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The use of the plural in "application**s**" suggests that you are not dealing with the entity directly, but with an `ArrayCollection` of Applications. `ArrayCollection` doesn't have a `__toString()`